# does dbpedia has separate Novel information also?

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia

wikipedia has a separate infobox for novels hence I was wondering does dbpedia has separate ontology for novels as its has for books?

Answer (score 1):

Infobox_novel is just a redirect to Infobox_book:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_novel

While there are thousands of pages using Infobox_book, there are a mere six using Infobox_novel:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Template:Infobox_novel?namespace=0

So in this case it probably doesn't make sense to add a new DBpedia class.

For the record, here's the class hierarchy of the DBpedia class Book:

http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/#Book

And here's some documentation on how to add new classes:

http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/Ontology_Editing